# R - Select IDs that meet multiple criteria from single column

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a list of IDs, each having multiple events. The data looks like an event log, i.e. one event per ID per row. For example:

```
n.ID=4
n.events=5
set.seed(1234)
df <- setNames(melt(replicate(n.ID, sort(sample(letters[c(1:10)], n.events))))[c(2:3)], c("ID", "Event"))
df

    > df
   ID Event
1   1     b
2   1     e
3   1     f
4   1     h
5   1     i
6   2     a
7   2     b
8   2     d
9   2     e
10  2     g
11  3     b
12  3     c
13  3     e
14  3     g
15  3     j
16  4     b
17  4     c
18  4     g
19  4     i
20  4     j
```

I want to select those IDs, that meet a list of criteria, that either use AND or OR.

For example:

1. those IDs that have events "b" AND "c" AND "g" --> results in ID 3 & 4
2. those IDs that have events "a" OR "h"         --> results in ID 1 & 2

The criteria vectors can be any length.

EDIT:

I am aware of %in% and "|", however,

```
keep.if <- c("b", "c", "g") # This list can be of any length
subset(df, Event %in% keep.if)
ID Event
1   1     b
7   2     b
10  2     g
11  3     b
12  3     c
14  3     g
16  4     b
17  4     c
18  4     g
```

I only want those that have 3 rows in the results, so i can do a table on this results, and select those IDs where the Freq == length(keep.if)... but I guess there should be an easier, less messy method...

I guess for the OR version I can just take:

```
unique(subset(df, Event %in% keep.if)$ID)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Are you familiar with the `%in%` operator and the `|` operator?

Comment: See EDIT in my post. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Question is not clear, please add expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a `table` then use `tidyr::spread` to create a contigency table type object. Then I would use `data.table` for easier sub setting and logical operations:

```
library(tidyr)

df.table<-as.data.frame(table(df)) %>% spread(Event, Freq)
df.table

ID a b c d e f g h i j
1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
2 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
3 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1
4 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1

library(data.table)
##easier to subset with

df.table<-data.table(df.table)
df.table[b & c & g]

ID a b c d e f g h i j
3 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1
4 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1

df.table[a | h]

ID a b c d e f g h i j
1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
2 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

Those are the 2 examples you gave in the question. You should  be able to do just about any operation you want. Also, if you only want to know which IDs satisfy your logic (and not their entire contingency table) then:

```
df.table[b & c & g]$ID
[1] 3 4
```